# How to get back deleted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Some days back, I had posted an answer to a question in Stack Overflow. And the author of the question marked it as a useful answer to their question. But someone deleted my answer. Is there any way to retrieve my deleted answer?

Comment: Do you have a link to the answer you are referring to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015964/how-to-publish-react-js-pwa-in-amazon-app-store

Comment: I you want to "undelete" it, the you would have to first edit it so it qualifies as an answer. There should be a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) on the deleted answer that explains the reasons for an answer to be deleted.

Comment: Your answer reads as `Please go through the steps mentioned in the documentation. I think it will help you to solve this problem <link>`. This is a link only answer. You need to provide the actual answer in your post itself and provide the link as a reference

Comment: But it say it need 5 votes to undelete the post

Comment: Yes... you need to first edit your post and add the solution.

Comment: This post discusses why links are not accepted as answers: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score -4):

You can get the list of your recently deleted answers from the link of your profile page, in the answer tab, bottom.

In your case, the list is on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/14698598).

Beside you, only the mods can see this link (although everybody over 10000 rep can see your deleted answers, but can not get their list).

Only the answers deleted in the last 60 days are visible here. A similar link exists also for your questions.

---

Now that I read the comments and I've seen your answer: you are right (user needs to read docs), but it does not qualify as an answer. This is why it was deleted. It was deleted by a mod, such posts can be undeleted only by mods. What you can do: you can improve your answer to make it acceptable, for example by using the docs the OP does not want to read. After that, you can flag the answer, click "needs mod intervention", and there you can politely ask the mod for an undeletion. He will likely do it, even if he thinks your answer is bad (the requirement for the undelete is that it should be answer, not that it should be a good one).

Comment: Considering the user already has a link to their deleted answer, I don't think this really answers the question. What the OP wants is to undelete the answer, not to recover [its content](https://cln.sh/iU5KdO).

Comment: @yivi Right. I should have read the comments as well.

Comment: You should have flagged as a duplicate also.

Comment: @SecurityHound What?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - What is confusing about that particular comment?  You indicated you should have read the comments before you submitted your answer.  I also was pointing out the fact, the question was a duplicate of an existing question, and you should have looked for a potential duplicate (since this question is asked often).

Comment: @SecurityHound Ok, so I understand. But reviewing is optional and not obligatory.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - I would disagree with that fact.  If you are going to answer a question, you should accept that reasonability, to make sure there isn't a duplicate before you go to that considerable effort of answering a question.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - **I stopped reviewing content on Stack Overflow 8 and half years ago.** However, you are happy to review those 2,700 questions I downvoted, I guarantee you the majority of those will have been deleted. [I actually made 42 edit suggestions, performed 152 reviews, and voted 3,600 times](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261581/security-hound?tab=votes&sort=all).  **I actually only downvoted 1,566 contributions and upvoted 2,032 contributions.**  Funny how my actually stats are not actually what you claim they were.